# Why does bootstrap-vue require me to install jquery and webpack manually, even though I have them installed globally?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack, vue-cli

Im setting up a new bootstrap-vue project using vue-cli by running the command
`vue init bootstrap-vue/webpack-simple my-project`.

Each time I start a new project, I have to install all the dependencies in the output below by hand. 
Am I missing something?

I already have installed jquery/webpack etc globally using `npm install -g webpack` but whenever I run the command I get the following output:

```
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is 
installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN babel-loader@6.4.1 requires a peer of webpack@1 || 2 || ^2.1.0- 
beta || ^2.2.0-rc but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies 
yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.2.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is 
installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 
(node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Im pretty new to understanding npm and js dependency management, and it just doesn't make sense that every time I spawn up a new project, I have to manually go down the line and install the various dependencies by hand. Am I missing something?

Comment: Those are just warnings, they are warning you of a _potential_ issue in the future

Comment: You can ignore them or you can add them to your requirements in package.json in order to satisfy the warnings

Comment: Ah I see, so in the case of jquery I may have issues if I use some feature in bootstrap that may need jquery installed. And to resolve the issue i can just reference them in my package.json file? Like so? `"dependencies": {
    "module: "*"
} `

Comment: Yes, that should do it